# Confusion between @Transactional and AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-transactions

Does @Transactional is replacement for  AOP in spring 3. are they same? Can I say @Transactional implements AOP internally ?

Answer (score 4):

The `@Transactionnal` annotation is just a simple way to declare that a method is (or all methods of a class are) transactionnal.

The Spring Framework will use an AOP proxy to intercept calls to the method and manage transaction.

So, we can say that `@Transactionnal` use AOP internally.

More information [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained)

Answer (score 1):

What you can say is that Spring uses AOP to add a transactional aspect to bean methods annotated with `@Transactional`: before executing such a method, it starts a transaction (if necessary), and after the method has been executed, it commits or rollbacks the transaction.