# Confusion with @Transactional

Tags: java, spring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confusion between @Transactional and AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112184/confusion-between-transactional-and-aop)

I am new to spring framework and  I am confuse between @Transactional and tx:advice , because I read that AOP use to provide declarative transaction management and @Transactional also does the same...are they same ? does @Transactional uses AOP internally ? where to use AOP and where to use @Transactional

Comment: Do you know what AOP is?

Answer (score 0):

@Transactonal is a more practical solution in all projects worked on in the past few years. In some very specific cases, however, I had also to use Spring AOP to allow the use of more than one JDBC connection/TransactionManager because @Transaction is tied to a single transaction
manager.

Answer (score 0):

`@Transactional` is just a simple way to declare that a method or all methods of a class (if placed at class level) are transactional.

Spring uses an AOP proxy to intercept calls to the method(s), starts a transaction (if necessary) and after the method has been executed, it commits or rollbacks the transaction.

Reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained